# How do I add a condition to a query?

Tags: 8, database

```
$acl_ids = array(1,2,3);
$database = \Drupal::database();

$result = $database
  ->query("SELECT {nid} FROM {acl_node} WHERE grant_update = :grant", 
    ['grant' => 1,])
  ->condition('acl_id', $acl_ids, 'in')
  ->fetchField();
```

Unfortunately the `->condition` part does not work, since I get the following error:

> Call to undefined method Drupal\Core\Database\Statement::condition()

What method should I instead use?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Conditions are only used in dynamic queries; the `query()` method is for running static SQL.

The dynamic version would be something like:

```
$result = $database
  ->select('acl_node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', ['nid'])
  ->condition('grant_update', 1)
  ->condition('acl_id', $acl_ids, 'IN')
  ->execute()
  ->fetchField();
```

And the static:

```
$result = $database
  ->query("SELECT nid FROM {acl_node} WHERE grant_update = :grant AND acl_id IN (:acl_ids[])", [':grant' => 1, ':acl_ids[]' => $acl_ids])
  ->fetchField();
```

Comment: i get `Placeholders must have a trailing [] if they are to be expanded with an array of values.` and I cant really figure out what the correct syntax is (using the static one)

Comment: @Alex Updated the answer, the change record is [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2401615) if you're interested

Comment: Thanks, I've already guessed it has to look like this but it still throws an error: `Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens: SELECT {nid} FROM {acl_node} WHERE grant_update = :grant AND acl_id IN (:acl_ids__0, acl_ids__1);`. Looks like a drupal bug?

Comment: @Alex `{nid}` tells Drupal nid is a table name, while it is a table row name. Remove those parentheses from your code.

Comment: Good spot @kiamlaluno, totally missed that. Yes you might be looking at a bug if it still doesn't work Alex, according to the change record and a quick look at https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Database!Connection.php/function/Connection%3A%3AexpandArguments/8.0.x, that should work in theory

Comment: @kiamlaluno still no luck. when I set `$acl_ids = array(2);` it works, though

Comment: Oh right, yeah `$acl_ids` needs to be an array, otherwise you should see the `Placeholders with a trailing [] can only be expanded with an array of values.` error

Comment: it is an array, but it seems `:acl_ids[]` gets seen as 1 placeholder while the array consists of more than 1 items, so the error occurs: `Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`. when I change the item count to 1 it works

Comment: @Clive the dynamic version claims it has no method `fetchField`

Comment: @Alex Needs to be executed, I assumed your code was based on [the documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Database!database.api.php/group/database/8.2.x) so I didn't go through every line of it

Comment: @Clive sorry, I am a noodle :) works now, thanks a bunch. any idea reg. the static one though?

Comment: Still trying to work that one out, will probably be a bit later but once I've got an idea I'll update this!

Comment: @Clive it should be `->fetchCol();`

Comment: It should be `fetchCol()` if you want multiple results, `fetchField()` if you want a single field from a single result, that's correct

Comment: It'd be easiest to that in the query; join the node table and check the type column for the one(s) you're interested in

Comment: Sorry, not got time at the moment. The docs I linked to will have everything you need, and if you're struggling just ask a new question

Answer (score 2):

The code you wrote is equivalent to the Drupal 7 code that used `db_query()`. You cannot use `condition()` with the object returned from `\Drupal::database()->query()`. I would also change your code in two points:

- You are using `{nid}` in your query, which is what you should use when nid is a table name, not a table field name <sup>*</sup>
- You are using `['grant' => 1,]` as array of arguments, when it should be `[':grant' => 1,]` basing on Drupal/PHP documentation (Notice the colon before the table field name.)

If you don't want to use functions that are going to be deprecated in Drupal 9, see the answer given by Clive. I will add that you can still use `db_query()` or `db_select()` also in Drupal 8. In fact, Drupal 8.2.x still contains 160 calls to `db_query()` and 128 calls to `db_select()`.

```
$acl_ids = array(1,2,3);

$result = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {acl_node} an WHERE an.grant_update = :grant AND an.acl_id IN ( :ids[] )", [':grant' => 1, ':ids[]' => $acl_ids]);

foreach ($result AS $row) {
  // access the node ID as $row['nid'].
}
```

This code is similar to the one used in [`history_read_multiple()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21history%21history.module/function/history_read_multiple/8.2.x).

```
  $result = db_query('SELECT nid, timestamp FROM {history} WHERE uid = :uid AND nid IN ( :nids[] )', array(
    ':uid' => \Drupal::currentUser()->id(),
    ':nids[]' => array_keys($nodes_to_read),
  ));
  foreach ($result as $row) {
    $nodes_to_read[$row->nid] = (int) $row->timestamp;
  }
  $history += $nodes_to_read;
```

#### Notes

Using `{nid}` would cause a wrong query being executed if Drupal is using prefixes for the table names. Still, it is not correct to use `{nid}` if you don't want Drupal to alter it as it alters a table name.

Comment: The colon shouldn't make any difference, it's passed straight through to PDO which doesn't mind if it's missing...

Comment: Drupal always use placeholders like :grant in the query and in the array. I have never checked if removing the colon gives an error, actually.

Comment: Yeah you're right, Drupal's convention is to use the colon unconditionally, but, at least in D7, it wasn't necessary because PDO doesn't care and the array was passed almost straight through. I can't imagine it would be different in D8, it would surely be more work to remove that ability than to just let it work as 'expected'. Worth a test though

Comment: In the example given on [PDOStatement::execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) I see the colon is used in both the places: `$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories FROM fruit WHERE calories < :calories AND colour LIKE :colour'); $sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT); $sth->bindValue(':colour', "%{$colour}%");`.

Comment: I think that changed in PHP 5.2.0: "The keys from input_parameters must match the ones declared in the SQL. Before PHP 5.2.0 this was silently ignored."

Comment: That must be something different, this still works fine in PHP 7: `db_query('SELECT * FROM node WHERE type = :type', ['type' => 'page'])->fetchAll();`. No difference between the result from that and the same line but using `':type' => `

Comment: Here's the line in PHP7's source which confirms it: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.0.6/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c#L366. The leading colon is definitely optional, intentionally so by the looks of it. As long as the param name in the SQL itself has the colon, no need to add it in the params array. So not the source of the OP's problem it would seem

Comment: Also the documentation for `PDOStatement::bindParam()` says the parameter is in the form `:name` when using named placeholders. it could be the code is a bit tolerant for some reason, but there is no warranty `name` will always work. Since they don't expressly say `name` is accepted, they could change that code without even reporting that as incompatibility.

Comment: They could, but they haven't; my only point is that it's not currently an error, so not responsible for the OP's issue (which you suggest _is_ the cause in the answer). I'm not advocating it should be used, personally I always go with the leading `:` for convention anyway

Comment: Let's not use the word _errors_ then. To split hairs, not even using `{nid}` is causing the error the OP is seeing, but I think it is better to point out that using `{nid}` is not something the OP should do. `:-)`

Comment: Yeah good point ;)